# ISO-1 C# language specification error for FastMember

Tags: c#, .net, fastmember

I loaded up the .net 3.5 FastMember from http://code.google.com/p/fast-member/source/checkout in VS 2010.

The compiler generates this error:

***feature 'static classes' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-1 C# language specification.***

How do we get past this?

Comment: The author is Marc Gravell, a very active SO member.

Comment: This has nothing to do with protobuf-net or dapper; please don't abuse tags

Comment: The only time I have seen such a message was using Mono. You are not using Mono perhaps?

Comment: @MarcGravell: okay on tags.  That was in response to "contact the author".

Comment: @leppie you can get that in VS too - just change the language version (I show the dialog in my answer) to ISO-1 and it'll do that.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Never saw that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISO-1 is C# 1.2; FastMember was specifically not designed to handle that. It also makes use of generics, which don't exist until ISO-2. It would probably be possible to get rid of all those, but I'm not sore of the benefit. The number of things that require C# 1.2 is ... extremely small.

Can you clarify the context here?

If you aren't intentionally limiting yourself to C# 1.2, then go to project properties, Advanced... and change the language version - "default" is fine (although it does build in ISO-2 aka C# 2.0, if you really want):

[image]

Comment: Context: loaded the project in VS 2010 instead of VS 2008.  Didn't expect that the conversion process would default to ISO-1.  Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @sgtz there is no reason it should of. The project **is** a VS 2010 project. It isn't **explicitly** set to *anything* in the .csproj file (I checked - there is no `<LangVersion>` element), so I can only conclude it is using your VS settings. I think, therefore, that this is down to your user-settings in VS.

Comment: strange VS behaviour on my machine then.  btw: unit tests all work fine.